# NextAuth jwt as header.Authorization bearer Token Next Js

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt, next.js, next-auth

I have an API built in node that technically it should take the cookie but is not getting it.

```
cookie: __Secure-next-auth.session-token || next-auth.session-token
```

Within my Next JS I am using nextAuth and inside my token payload I have the following attributes:

```
{
  "name": "Justin",
  "email": "justinzu93@gmail.com",
  "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7Il9pZCI6IjYwMWUwMWViZjNjZjkyMjcwMDI3ZmIzMCJ9LCJleHAiOjE2MTI4Nzc3ODEsImlhdCI6MTYxMjYxODU4MX0.BY7kVTHF5mhzTr6uUhyBmxXYYsm3LlMYnlULSzWZdc0",
  "_id": "601e01ebf3cf92270027fb30",
  "iat": 1612620162,
  "exp": 1612630962
}
```

So, my Idea is to get the cookie from node.JS , but is not possible. Any help please

This is how looks my cookies:

[image]

I would like to mention this is how i get the cookie from node:

```
const jwtExtractor = (req) => {
  let token = null;
  if (req.headers.authorization) {
    token = req.headers.authorization.replace("Bearer ", "").trim();
  } else if (req.body.token) {
    token = req.body.token.trim();
  } else if (req.query.token) {
    token = req.query.token.trim();
  } else if (req && req.cookies["next-auth.session-token"]) {
    const userCookie = jwt.decode(req.cookies["next-auth.session-token"]);
    token = userCookie.accessToken;
  }

  // if (token) {
  //   // Decrypts token
  //   token = auth.decrypt(token)
  // }
  return token;
};
```

Also I don't know why I can not access Session() inside useEffect hook (next JS).

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you're using some middleware, you should access the cookies string through `req.headers.cookie`.

Comment: yes, I am using a middleware that get the cookies from header , body or cookie , but with cookies ir returns an empty object, it looks like it does not exists

Comment: And what middleware is that?

Comment: I am using passport

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of hard to tell exactly what is happening with you code because I can't see an actual call being made through the network. But based on what you have provided, my best guess is that your `jwtExtractor` code is just a little off or that your token isn't being passed through the network. My suggestion to debug is first, look at the network call and look at the "Request Headers" and make sure you see your token being passed. Once you see it being passed, then you should know which object your `jwtExtractor` code should be accessing.